# php хранение паролей (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, php7

Везде пишут что не стоит хранить пароли в открытом виде... 
Собственно вопросы: как хранить тогда пароли? Чем и как шифровать?
P.s. Проект на Laravel, все логины и пароли вынесены в .env файл

Comment: О каких паролях речь?

Comment: От сервисов, например api, bitcoin node, база данных (mysql) и много много других

Comment: Ни разу не встречал, чтобы их предлагали хранить в каком-то неоткрытом виде

Comment: так или иначе чтобы расшифровать и всё работало автоматически нужно будет указать где-то пароль для расшифровки. а если его указать, то смысла никакого в шифровании нет. Так что никак. Получить доступ к .env не получится просто так. Так что ставьте нормальный пароль на хостинг.

Comment: Спасибо за советы

Comment: Самый простейший вариант - прогнать через MD5. Но данный метод шифрования уже не столь надёжен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего речь шла о паролях зарегистрированных пользователях.

При использовании стандартного механизма аутентификации `make:auth`, пароли новых пользователей будут шифроваться автоматически.

Если используете свой механизм то хелпер [bcrypt](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-bcrypt)  в помощь:

> $password = bcrypt('my-secret-password');

В файле .env находятся данные конфигурации, которые позволяют подключиться к БД и уже там хранить данные ваших пользователей и их зашифрованные пароли.